# Database management system for e-commerce website

Tags: mysql, database, e-commerce

i have just started designing an e-commerce service with different categories of products to offer (mobile phones, tablets, camera etc.). The way i am designing my database is like this:

1. category (id, name) - this table will get a fk reference from product_pool table.
2. product_pool (id, name, brand, price, category) - this table will contain all products from al categories

and tables for every category, for e.g.

- cat_mobile (product, os, cpu, ram, storage etc.)
- cat_tv (product, type, size etc.)

products in these tables will be referenced from product_pool.

Example:
[image]

I believe that type of approach will help me with facet searching and better management of product details. Only problem i see here is, a table for every category, making my database cluttered.

I needed some suggestions regarding my approach and some insights that i might be overlooking in this stage of development.

Comment: You might consider the [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. in EAV model, i believe that there is  huge risk of data redundancy for e.g. same entity will have same attribute value listed twice in the table. With my approach, even though data redundancy is possible, but it can be easily fixed i.e. for e.g. deleting row with same product in cat_mobile. Also if product in cat_mobile has unique constraint, this problem can be totally be avoided.

Comment: In an EAV table, you'd have multiple records for each product: one for each attribute it possesses.  No product would have "same attribute value listed twice", though a single attribute will obviously recur for each product that possesses it.  This isn't really "redundant", as it's distinct information, though if you're concerned about storage space you could use a different data type for the attribute identifier, eg an integer attribute code (perhaps FK to an Attributes table which might even identify the set of attributes each product category expects).

Comment: I understand that entity will have each record for its every attribute. My concern if(by mistake) attribute of an entity is valued twice e.g. e1's attrbute a1 is valued twice v1 and v2 i.e. two records containing same entity, attribute but different values. Sure they can be hunted and deleted, but it will be quiet a pain to operate like this on 10 of 1000s of records. My point is, **maintaining** attribute values of an entity be bit challenging with huge noof of records. Thanks for discussing btw.

Comment: Define a unique constraint over `(entity, attribute)` (indeed, that's usually the primary key of an EAV table) and that can *never* happen.

Comment: unique constraint over (entity, attribute)? how can i do it? Applying unique constraint to to entity or attribute columns separately is off course not possible in EAV model. How can i implement   "Define a unique constraint over (entity, attribute)". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE eav ADD UNIQUE (entity, attribute)` (but, as I said, it's usually the primary key—so a separate unique constraint would be unnecessary).